# Weird negative number after % operation

Tags: c

So I have something like the following,

```
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int i=0;
    int n=10000000000;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        a[i++]=n%10;
        printf("we have n  is %d\n", n);
        printf("we have n mod 10 is %d\n", n%10);
        n/=10;
        printf("we have%d\n", a[i]);
    }
```

Somehow I would always get a negative number when the n mod 10 is '0‘， can someone tell me why?

Comment: You should relate to your compiler warnings

Comment: `10000000000` is larger than a 32-bit value (`0x2540BE400`), so `int` won't hold it. You're getting something different in `n`.

Comment: @Siva, your comment is certainly not on the nice side. If you don't like a question: (1) you may downvote (2) comment on what you don't like about it. Just ranting is not appropriate.

Comment: Note: "we have n mod 10 is %d\n" implies the "modulo" operator whereas, [in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Common_pitfalls), `%` is the "remainder" operator.  The subtle difference are most apparent when at least one of the operands is negative.

Answer (score 11):

`int` is too small to hold that number. You are getting an overflow which is causing `n` to actually be a negative number, so you get a negative value for the modulo operation.

Answer (score 2):

The number is well past the limit of int on positive side.
You can run following codes to know the limits on integers in your OS

**C:**

```
#include <limits.h>
const int min_int = INT_MIN;
const int max_int = INT_MAX;
```

**C++:**

```
#include <limits>
const int min_int = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
const int max_int = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

**What you need to do:**

Choose another data type like `double`. You can also choose something like `long int` or simply `long` or `size_t` or `int64_t` which are each at least 64 bits.

For comparison:

- signed int: -32767 to 32767
- unsigned int: 0 to 65535
- signed long:-2147483647 to 2147483647
- unsigned long: 0 to 4294967295

**Why negative?**

The negative number happens because a typical `signed int` lies between `-32767 to 32767`
and then 32767 is represented as overflow. So this will be a negative number after truncating the overflow.

> Also note that the `sizeof` a type is determined by the compiler,
>   which doesn't have to have anything to do with the actual hardware
>   (though it typically does); in fact, different compilers on the same
>   machine can have different values for these.

Comment: `double` is floating point, there is no reason to use it here. Use a larger integer type instead: `long long` or (preferably) `uint64_t`.

Comment: @Lundin Yes you correct. +1 to you! added to my answer as you suggested.